# Could not initialize class org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner

Tags: java, maven

When I changed my spring version 4.2.4 to 5.3.22 then my test classes are failed.

and throwing error like "Could not initialize class org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner"

Please any one help me
[image]

I have a already tried to updgrade the JUnit Version 1.10 to 1.12 but not worked

Answer (score 0):

You moved to Junit 5. To make it Junit 4 compatible, you can use:

```
@RunWith(org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform.JUnitPlatform.class)
```

It would be part of `junit-platform-runner.jar` which you need as a dependency.

Comment: Hi @aatwork, Thanks for the reply.  
After the Clean up Command and stay with JUnit Version 1.12. The Issue is gone